# Have CSS3 spin start slow then end slow?

Tags: css, css-animations

This is not a question that can be solved by using `ease-in`.

If I have an element that I want to spin in CSS3 for a certain amount of time, but that starts off slow and ends slow, how can I do this?

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

div{
  background-image:-webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(51,51,51,1) 20%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,rgba(51,51,51,1) 40%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%,rgba(51,51,51,1) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,rgba(51,51,51,1) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 80%,rgba(51,51,51,1) 100%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-animation-name: spin; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 60.5;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
```

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. My animation runs for a total of 121 seconds, since it takes 2 seconds for one spin to complete, so 60.5 spins will take a total of 121 seconds (if my math is incorrect, please tell me). This works fine, except that I want the div to start spinning off slow, then completed all 59 rotations, then end slow for the last one.

I'd like to use pure CSS for this, if possible.

Comment: If you don't mind adding _a little_ javascript, you can write 3 animations and listen to `animationend` event to change key frame names...

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without JS? :D

Comment: If it really has to be pure CSS...wrap 3 `div`s together and use 3 animations, one for out most `div` to spin the first round, one delaying a few seconds and spin the "in most" `div` for 59 rounds, and one delaying ~100 seconds and spin the middle `div` for last rounds. You'll have to do the math of course :)

Comment: Could you post an example.. :)

Comment: e.g. `<div class="first_round"><div class="last_round"><div class="main_spin"></div></div></div>`,in CSS, `div.main_spin{animation-delay:3s;}div.last_round{animation-delay:100s;}`

Comment: Post one below as an answer, that way I can accept it as a solution so others can also see it. Also, I'd suggest putting a test into a jSFiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry that I don't have a JSFiddle...

**Edit**: I used a relative solution in my experiment: [CSS3 Clock](http://passerby.heliohost.org/clock/), could that count as a half fiddle? :D

**Edit #2**: JSFiddle provided by @Charlie: http://jsfiddle.net/7DPnc

If it really has to be pure CSS, I would suggest wrapping 3 `div`s together and spin them separately:

CSS

```
div.first_round
{
-webkit-animation-duration:3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
}
div.last_round
{
-webkit-animation-duration:3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:1.5;
-webkit-animation-delay:100s; /* you'll have to do the math */
}
div.main_round
{
-webkit-animation-duration:2s;
-webkit-animation-delay:3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:59;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="first_round">
<div class="last_round">
<div class="main_round">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Or if you don't mind using a little JS, listen to `animationend` event...

Comment: @Charlie OK you get the idea :)

Answer (score 2):

You need 60 spins in 120 seconds right?

Lets first change the iteration count to 1.

```
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
```

and the duration to 120 seconds

```
-webkit-animation-duration: 120s;
```

Now set the amount of spins. (360deg x 60spins)

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(21600deg); }
}
```

And now we'll modify that to set the timing. (shave a rotation off each side, add to new section)

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  10% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
  90% { -webkit-transform: rotate(20880deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(21600deg); }
}
```

Lastly, we set the easing function to linear in order to avoid the stop that will occur between keyframe sections if you use a curve. (replace with ease, ease-out, etc to see what I mean)

```
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
```

You can easily tweak the timing by changing duration, and the keyframe percentages.

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/koGKw)